# Is this switch of order of summation legal?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^3} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{k^{3m}} \to \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^3k^{3m}} \to \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{3(m+1)}} \to \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{3m}} \to (A) \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m (\zeta(3m) - 1)$$

I’m trying to evaluate

$$(B) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^3 + 1}$$

So I compared A and B on wolfram alpha and they’re off by one. Is it the weird switching of order of summation I did? I’d like to know.

Comment: For $k = 1$ the inner series on the left doesn't converge. Is the $k = 1$ a typo? Also, you change the summation range for $k$ when you replace $3(m+1)$ with $3m$. Something went wrong here, but there are several candidates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your manipulative mistake is in the third step:

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^{3(m+1)}}\ne\sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k^{3m}}\;.$$

The shift from $m+1$ to $m$ in the exponent requires a change in the limits on $m$, not those on $k$. In fact

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^{3(m+1)}}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty(-1)^{m-1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^{3m}}\;.$$

You also don’t want to allow $k=1$ in your first double summation, as the inner series diverges then.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath: You’re welcome!